# Laravel controller for form validation skinny

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I'm trying to make controllers skinny as possible. I use repositories for accessing the database and I use Services to do other stuff. In this case, I use it to insert a new post to the database. For validation I use Jeffery Way's validation package for Laravel.

**PostController.php**

```
<?php

use Laracasts\Validation\FormValidationException;

use Dnianas\Post\PostCreationService;
use Dnianas\Post\PostRepository;

use Dnianas\Forms\PostForm;

class PostController extends BaseController
{

    /*
     * Dnianas\Services\PostCreationService
     */
    protected $post;

    /*
    * The post repository
     */
    protected $posts;

    /**
     * @param PostForm $postForm
     * @param PostCreationService $post
     * @param PostRepository $postRepo
     */
    public function __construct(PostForm $postForm, PostCreationService $post, PostRepository $postRepo)
    {
        $this->posts = $postRepo;
        $this->postForm = $postForm;
        $this->post = $post;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth');
    }


    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function create()
    {
        // Get the input
        $input = Input::all();

        // Validate it
        try {
            $this->postForm->validate($input);
        } catch(FormValidationException $e) {
            return Response::json([
                'success' => 'false',
                'message' => 'You didn\'t enter anything, Post cannot be empty.'
            ]);
        }

        // Insert it to the database
        $post = $this->post->create($input, Auth::user()->id);

        // Get the html content from the view
        $html = View::make('posts.post', ['post_id' => $post->id])->render();

        // Return a message along with the html content
        return Response::json([
            'success' => 'true',
            'message' => 'Your post has been successfuly posted!',
            'post_html' => $html
        ]);

    }
```

**PostForm.php**

```
<?php namespace Dnianas\Forms;

use Laracasts\Validation\FormValidator;

class PostForm extends FormValidator
{
    /**
     * Validation rules for when the user creates a post
     * @var array
     */
    protected $rules = [
        'post_content' => 'required'
    ];

}
```

**PostCreationService.php**

```
namespace Dnianas\Post;

class PostCreationService 
{

    /**
     * @param $input
     * @param $user_id
     * @return \Post
     */
    public function create($input, $user_id)
    {
        // Validation passed to we insert it to our database
        $post = new \Post;
        $post->post_content = $input['post_content'];
        $post->posted_date  = \Carbon::now();
        $post->user_id      = $user_id;
        $post->save();

        return $post;
    }
}
```

Is this controller skinny enough? Can it get any skinnier? If so, then how?

Comment: You can use [Laravel events](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events) while saving posts. This way you don't need to check validation in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

- You can rewrite your entire variable section and constructor with PHP 8 [constructor promotion](https://stitcher.io/blog/constructor-promotion-in-php-8):

```php
class PostController extends BaseController
{
    /** Description */
    public function __construct(protected PostForm $postForm, 
                                protected PostCreationService $post, 
                                protected PostRepository $postRepo) {}
    // rest of controller
}
```

- In PostForm, I would put the namespace on its own line.
- Instead of using the FormValidator package, you can use [FormRequests](https://dev.to/othmane_nemli/different-ways-to-use-laravel-form-requests-5bmb) which are built into Laravel and do the same thing.
- Is it really just `'post_content' => 'required'`? The value may be longer than you can store in the database. It may be a .php file or some junk for all you know. Maybe `'required|string|max:255'`?
- The comments "Get the input" and "Validate it" are too obvious to be useful
- You could have used the helper `now()` in `$post->posted_date  = \Carbon::now();` but actually I question if you need posted_date at all because it will equal `created_at` from [`timestamps`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-timestamps) which is done automatically (and can be updated at a later date).
- Why do you pass `Auth::user()->id` to PostCreationService's create method when you can just move it inside there? (Remember, you can use `actingAs($user)` when testing.)
- Your methods should all declare their [parameter and return types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Dwight Watson's Validating Trait](https://github.com/dwightwatson/validating). I like to use it with:

```
protected $throwValidationExceptions = true;
```

Validation of `Eloquent` models occurs automatically according to the rules defined on the model and if it fails, a `ValidatingException` is thrown that you can catch further up the application stack. For example, I might put the following exception handler somewhere like `app/global/start.php`

```
App::error(function (\Watson\Validating\ValidationException $exception)
{
    Log::error($exception);
    // I prefer 'success' => 'false' to be expressed in the response code
    return Response::json([
        'message' => $exception->getErrors()->first(),
    ], 422); // Unprocessable entity
});
```

Them my controllers end up looking more like this:

```
public function create()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    // Validation occurs automatically during object creation
    $post = $this->post->create($input, Auth::user()->id);
    $html = View::make('posts.post', ['post_id' => $post->id])->render();

    // I prefer "success" to be expressed by the 200 OK response code
    return Response::json([
        'message' => 'Your post has been successfully posted!',
        'post_html' => $html
    ]); // not specifying a response code implies 200 OK

}
```

But it's really just a matter of personal preference at this point. Your code looks good to me.

## tl;dr +1 would pull & merge